# Error starting ProtonVPN from CLI using SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, vpn

If I'm physically at my desktop, I can start protonvpn with no issue using the command `protonvpn-cli c`.

However, when I'm connected remotely via an SSH connection and run the same command, I get this error:
`Unable to setup reconnect. Please make sure that you have access to internet or that you've previously connected to another server.`

I've not had any luck searching around on forums yet, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and using the official ProtonVPN package (https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-ubuntu-vpn-setup/)

Comment: After searching, CPH found [this fix](https://djangocas.dev/blog/linux/troubleshooting-protonvpn-EnableIPv6LeakProtectionError-Unable-to-add-IPv6-leak-protection-connection-interface/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, finally found this fix!

https://djangocas.dev/blog/linux/troubleshooting-protonvpn-EnableIPv6LeakProtectionError-Unable-to-add-IPv6-leak-protection-connection-interface/

To fix this issue, we need add a `PolicyKit` rule for the `NetworkManager`.

Use root to create a file name `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla`, the content as below:

```
Identity=unix-user:<your username>
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.*
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

Replace `<your username>` with your Linux username.

For multiple username:

`Identity=unix-user:<username1>;unix-user:<username2>`

Check `PolicyKit` Authentication Agent exist or not:

```
# ls /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1': No such file or directory
```

If file does not exist, install it by `apt-get install policykit-1-gnome`:

```
# apt-get install policykit-1-gnome

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  policykit-1-gnome
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 68.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 508 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 policykit-1-gnome amd64 0.105-7 [68.2 kB]
Fetched 68.2 kB in 0s (752 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package policykit-1-gnome.
(Reading database ... 133186 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../policykit-1-gnome_0.105-7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking policykit-1-gnome (0.105-7) ...
Setting up policykit-1-gnome (0.105-7) ...
```

If `policykit-1-gnome` does not exist, try to use `apt-cache` search `PolicyKit Authentication Agent` to get correct package name:

```
# apt-cache search PolicyKit Authentication Agent
lxqt-policykit - LXQt authentication agent for PolicyKit
lxpolkit - LXDE PolicyKit authentication agent
mate-polkit - MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
mate-polkit-bin - MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1 (executable wrapper script)
mate-polkit-common - MATE authentication agent for PolicyKit-1 (common files)
libpolkit-agent-1-0 - PolicyKit Authentication Agent API
libpolkit-agent-1-dev - PolicyKit Authentication Agent API - development files
policykit-1-gnome - authentication agent for PolicyKit
polkit-kde-agent-1 - KDE dialogs for PolicyKit
ukui-polkit - UKUI authentication agent for PolicyKit-1
```

Then try to run `protonvpn-cli` connect again. You should be good to go

Comment: @Nmath you're right lol. In my excitement of finally finding a fix, I didn't think about that. Updating the answer now